# A matrix between vectors, and inequality!

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, matrix-analysis, matrix-equations

I have an inequality as follows

$$s^T\phi\leq -|s|^TA$$

where $s$, $\phi$ and $A$ are vectors with appropriate dimensions. I want to prove that this inequality holds for the following too

$$s^TM\phi\leq -|s|^TMA$$

where $M$ has positive eigenvalues. Intuitively, it seems to be right. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not clear on your notation. Is $|s|^T$ the norm of $s$ as a vector? What does the ${}^T$ do?

Comment: Hi, @BenMcKay, $T$ is the transpose,  and $|.|$ is the absolute value (element-wise). That is $|s|=[|s_1| \ldots |s_n| ]^T$

Comment: This is the kind of claims that I start believing in only after I have done at least 10.000 random experiments without finding any counterexample...

Answer (score 1):

Please check my arithmetic. Let $\phi=(1 \ 1)^T$, $s=(1 \ 1)^T$, $A=(-1/2 \ \ {-2})^T$. Then try 
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I seem to get $s^T \phi = 2$, $-|s|^T=(-1 \, -1)$, $-|s|^T A = 2 + 1/2$, $s^T M \phi = 5$, $-|s|^T M A =4$.

Answer (score 1):

Even you let $\phi=A$, the statement still not hold in general.

Let $s=(1,1)$, $\phi=A=(1,-1)$, $M=diag(2,1)$.